# elegant way of capturing a reference to an integer variable?

Tags: input, rust, reference

I have this snippet:

```
let mut animation_index = 0 as usize;
let mut ptr : *mut usize = &mut animation_index as _;
{
    io_context.window().add_key_callback(
        Box::new(move |key_states| {
            if key_states[KbKey::Space.to_index()] == KeyActionState::Press
            {
                unsafe {
                *ptr += 1;
                println!("{}", animation_index);
                }
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Basically it adds a callback such that if and when I press space, the integer variable `animation_index` goes up by 1. This works, but requires the use of mutable pointers and unsafe, which is very ugly.

I'd like to have the same logic but ideally do it with pure safe rust isntead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to share a mutable value across threads.

Typically, this is done with atomics, `Arc<Mutex<T>>` or `Arc<RwLock<T>>`.

```
use std::synce::{Arc, RwLock};

let mut animation_index = Arc::new(RwLock::new(0usize));
{
    // a clone of the counter that can be moved into the callback
    let animation_index = animation_index.clone();
    io_context.window().add_key_callback(
        Box::new(move |key_states| {
            if key_states[KbKey::Space.to_index()] == KeyActionState::Press
            {
                let index = animation_index.write().unwrap();
                *index += 1;
                println!("{}", index);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

With atomics it would look something like this:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

let mut animation_index = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(0));
{
    // a clone of the counter that can be moved into the callback
    let animation_index = animation_index.clone();
    io_context.window().add_key_callback(
        Box::new(move |key_states| {
            if key_states[KbKey::Space.to_index()] == KeyActionState::Press
            {
                let index = animation_index.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
                println!("{}", index);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: The program is single threaded at the moment.

Comment: @Makogan you didn't provide any context about the library you are using, but it's likely that a UI libarary types will assume that it _could_ be multithreaded and you'll need to use threadsafe types. If that turns out not to be the case, you would use `Rc<Cell<T>>` instead, but the code would look very similar.

Comment: How would you read  the resulting value in the variable `animation_index`? 

When I try reading the value after creating the closure the compiler claims the value was moved into the closure and no longer accessible.

Comment: @Makogan you can clone the Arc (I have updated it)